# Como carregar a lista de itens do p:selectOneMenu ao clicar para abrir o dropdown?

Tags: java, primefaces, jsf-2.2

Gostaria que meu p:selectOneMenu recarregasse os itens e mostrasse as opções toda vez que eu clicasse para abrir o dropdown, alguém já tentou fazer isso? Se sim, como faço?

Comment: Porque vc precisa atualizar a lista no momento do click? Não seria melhor atualizar a lista a partir de algum evento? (Ex: gravação/exclusão)

Comment: Na verdade será inserido nessa lista elementos que estão sendo manipulados por vários usuários diferentes ao mesmo tempo, sendo que estes vários usuários podem adicionar ou remover itens dessa lista, então convém atualizar a listagem toda vez que abrir o selectOneMenu.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode mudar o get da lista no bean:

```
public List<Bla> getListaBla() {
    updateBlaList();
    return this.blaList;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode disparar uma requisição ajax que atualize a lista..

```
<p:selectOneMenu value="#{bean.object.property}" id="myId" required="true">
    <f:selectItems value="#{bean.list}" />
    <f:ajax event="click" listener="#{bean.updateList}" />
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

Não é a forma ideal para se fazer.. a melhor forma seria ao recarregar a página já trazer todos os itens.

Comment: Já havia tentado de maneira parecida. Tentei aqui novamente e não funcionou.

Answer (score 0):

E se você incluir um poll? De tempos em tempos você atualiza seu select...

```
<p:poll interval="3" listener="#{counterView.increment}" update="txt_count" />
```

Comment: Não seria uma boa solução. A consulta a todas os itens da lista deve ser feita quando o usuário pedir, se tivéssemos controle do tamanho da lista e esse tamanho fosse bem pequeno poderíamos até pensar no caso mesmo sabendo que não seria a solução ótima...